# Unit test returns Cannot read property 'open' of undefined message

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular15

I am codng ia Unit Test on a code and component working. I can't understand what's going on. I have tried different approaches but I always get the same error. I have simplified the Code of the Unit Test to the maximum so that you can see the problem more easily. Thank you

**COMPONENT**

```
openUpdate(rowSelected: iData) {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogEditComponent, {});
        dialogRef.componentInstance.dialogRef = dialogRef;
        dialogRef.componentInstance.selectedData = rowSelected;
        const sub = dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd.subscribe((data: iData) => {
            if (data) {
                this.update(data);
            }
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
            sub.unsubscribe();
        });
    }
```

**SPEC.TS**

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const dialogSpy = {
      open: jasmine.createSpy('open').and.returnValue({
        componentInstance: {
          onAdd: jasmine.createSpyObj('onAdd', ['subscribe'])
        },
        afterClosed: () => {
          return jasmine.createSpyObj('afterClosed', ['subscribe']);
        }
      })
    };
    toastrServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ToastrService', ['success', 'error']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Component1, DialogEditComponent],
      imports: [MatDialogModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialogSpy },
        { provide: ToastrService, useValue: toastrServiceSpy },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });
```

........

```
it('should open the edit dialog with the selected data', async () => {
    await component.openUpdate(mockData[0]);
    expect(dialogSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/features/component1.component.spec.ts:99:22)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
        at apply (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:409:30)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:303:43)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:408:56)
        at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:169:47)
        at apply (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1326:38)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:443:35)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the issue in the `.spec.ts` file like so, it means `open` is `undefined` in your unit test (not component file so the mocking is most likely done properly).

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/features/component1.component.spec.ts:99:22)
```

I bet the issue is the way you declare `dialogSpy`.

Do the following (pay attention to comments with !!):

```
// !! Declare dialogSpy outside of the first `beforeEach` so all `it` blocks
// will have access to it.
let dialogSpy: any;

beforeEach(async () => {
    // !! Remove const here and assign dialogSpy to what it should be
    dialogSpy = {
      open: jasmine.createSpy('open').and.returnValue({
        componentInstance: {
          onAdd: jasmine.createSpyObj('onAdd', ['subscribe'])
        },
        afterClosed: () => {
          return jasmine.createSpyObj('afterClosed', ['subscribe']);
        }
      })
    };
    toastrServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ToastrService', ['success', 'error']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Component1, DialogEditComponent],
      imports: [MatDialogModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialogSpy },
        { provide: ToastrService, useValue: toastrServiceSpy },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

it('should open the edit dialog with the selected data', async () => {
    await component.openUpdate(mockData[0]);
    // !! Log out dialogSpy and make sure it is not undefined
    console.log(dialogSpy);
    expect(dialogSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Hi AliF50. If I remove const from const dialogSpy, the variable shows me this error:  Type '{ open: Spy<Func>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'MatDialog': _overlay, _defaultOptions, _parentDialog, _dialogRefConstructor, and 16 more.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Change `let dialogSpy: MatDialog` to `let dialogSpy: any;`. We are being more loose with the types but I think it's okay for testing.

Comment: Wow. It works. Many Thanks! I need to integrate this part in the whole test, I hope I can. But many thanks again!